# Socket Programming for chat on Google App Server

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, tcp, chat

Disclaimer: I am a novice programmer

I am currently following a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

To build a chat application on the iPhone using socket servers. For other purposes, I am using Google App Engine to maintain the backend of my app and hold onto other pieces of data. It only makes sense to have all my backend code located in one area so I was wondering whether Google App Engine will support my socket Programming as there seems to be quite a few restrictions as such: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/#limitations-and-restrictions

In fact it almost looks as if there are too many restrictions, however google on the page said that there are "Libraries that import socket, such as poplib or nntplib, and that don't violate the limitations and restrictions listed below, should work without modification." meaning that there are things that I can do to modify my work to allow it to work on the Google App Engine.

**My Question:** Is it possible to use my learning of socket programming to maintain a backend for my chat on the google app engine? If there is, how do I modify my file if I need to. If there isn't, what app server should I look into so that I can at least hold my chat backend on another server if not at google app engine. If you think that I should take another method altogether to implement chat in my iPhone app, I would love to hear that as well. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shall not open the socket yourself, you should use [APNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) on iPhone and [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) on Android, so it's not your app that will open (send keepalives, reopen when closed, reopen when connectivity change, etc...) the TCP socket. Also you'll be able to receive data (be spawned) when even if your app is closed.

Received messages (from APNS/GCM) can contains the actual data, or simply be a "Hey, you may go check for messages on the server". To send message you may simply use an HTTP request.

Comment: "To send message you may simply use an HTTP request." Sockets would be faster though, no?